# Get other users data custom value

Tags: users

how can I get all (custom) data from other users ?

With my admin account, I want to show them in a page.

For example :

> - user 1 :
>
>   - name
>   - age
>   - custValue
>
>     - custValue1 / 2  / 3

I want to get custValue and the other data (custValue is the most important)

Example of values that I want to show :

[image]

Comment: What is custValue ? Is that is field for user .

Comment: This is a custom field of my users

Comment: You mean this value also related to user 1 .

Comment: Yes, this is indeed for user 1. But user 2 also have it's own custValue (which could be the same than user 1)

Comment: Please explain your user field properly and if it is possible upload a screenshot of your user fields .

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 :

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
$value = $user->field_name->value;
```

For multiple values, use

```
$value = $user->get('field_name')->getValue();
```

Comment: This is only for 1 user, right  ? I need to get data from all users, should I look at User::loadMultiple() ?

Comment: Load all user and print same thing in loop.

Comment: you can User::loadMultiple($uids); and loop

Comment: LoadMultiple isn't supposed to avoid to loop ?

Comment: you can try drupal  entityQuery https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x